# MATLAB parse function, parameter not registred

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to parse a function with parameters and values, however, when I run the function, the parameters are not being registred. Here's my code:

```
function A = my_function(B,varargin)
inp = inputParser;

addRequired(inp,'B',@ischar);
addParameter(inp,'C',' world',@ischar);

A = strcat(B,C);
disp(A)
end
```

When I try to execute the function:

```
B = 'Hello';
my_function('Hello')
```

I recieve this error

```
Undefined function or variable 'C'.
```

The expected output should be

```
A =
    Hello world
```

What am I missing here?

**Edit**

So here is the solution, thanks to @bendervader

```
function A = my_function(B,varargin)
inp = inputParser;

addRequired(inp,'B',@ischar);
addParameter(inp,'C',' world',@ischar);

parse(inp,B,varargin{:});

A = strcat(inp.Results.B,inp.Results.C);
disp(A)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at inputParser documentations? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser-class.html

First, the variable "C" was never declared. So, you get the error.

Here is a short (untested example) of the inputparser

```
p = inputParser;
addRequired(p, 'B', @ischar);
addParameter(p, 'C', 'world', @ischar);

% now you need to 'parse'
parse(p, B, varargin{:}); % this will get 'C' for you from varargin
A = strcat(p.B, p.C); % get the variables you want from the inputParse
disp(A)
```

Comment: So, I added `parse(inp, B, varargin{:})`; to my code and modefied `A = strcat(B,C)` --> `A = strcat(inp.B,inp.C);`. But now I'm getting the following error:_No appropriate method, property, or field 'B' for class 'inputParser'. Error in my_function (line 9). A = strcat(inp.B,inp.C); _

Comment: I found the solution: `strcat(inp.Results.B,inp.Results.C)` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you OK with doing this instead:

```
function A = my_function(B,C)
  if nargin < 2
    C = ' world'
  end
  A = strcat(B,C);
  disp(A)
end
```

here `nargin` tells you how many parameters were supplied at the function application.  If it is less than 2, then set `C` to its default value

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, but it's not what I'm looking for. I want to be able to use parameters-values.